# ASP. NET webpage: create a search box to search data from a table in Oracle

Tags: asp.net, sql, oracle, search

I'm trying to create an ASP.NET webpage to output a textbox, then user will enter the key in this textbox and I use that key to put into WHERE condition in SQL code to output data that matches the key. For example, user enters ArtistID in the textbox and I need to print the table SPEEDOFSALEREPORT using

> SELECT * FROM SPEEDOFSALEREPORT WHERE ArtistID = "the key that user just enter"

but I don't know how. My code below creates a text box and print all rows in the table. Please give me a hint. I tried googling all days but cannot find the answer. Thank you.

This is my updated Default.aspx

```
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtArtistID" runat="server" /><br /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" CssClass="submit" />

    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TRANSACTIONID" HeaderText="TRANSACTIONID" 
                    SortExpression="TRANSACTIONID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="WORKID" HeaderText="WORKID" 
                    SortExpression="WORKID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ARTISTID" HeaderText="ARTISTID" 
                    SortExpression="ARTISTID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DATEACQUIRED" HeaderText="DATEACQUIRED" 
                    SortExpression="DATEACQUIRED" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DATESOLDID" HeaderText="DATESOLDID" 
                    SortExpression="DATESOLDID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TURNAROUNDDAYS" HeaderText="TURNAROUNDDAYS" 
                    SortExpression="TURNAROUNDDAYS" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ASKINGPRICE" HeaderText="ASKINGPRICE" 
                    SortExpression="ASKINGPRICE" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SALESPRICE" HeaderText="SALESPRICE" 
                    SortExpression="SALESPRICE" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SALESMARGIN" HeaderText="SALESMARGIN" 
                    SortExpression="SALESMARGIN" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="Data Source=oracle2;User ID=****;Password=****;Unicode=True" 
    ProviderName="System.Data.OracleClient" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM SPEEDOFSALEREPORT WHERE ARTISTID = @artistID;">

    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="artistID" ControlID="txtArtistID" PropertyName="Text" />
    </SelectParameter>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

check this line :

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="Data Source=oracle2;User ID=******;Password=***********;Unicode=True" 
        ProviderName="System.Data.OracleClient" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM SPEEDOFSALEREPORT">
```

Correct using this :

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="Data Source=oracle2;User ID=******;Password=***********;Unicode=True" 
        ProviderName="System.Data.OracleClient" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM SPEEDOFSALEREPORT"
        FilterExpression="Artistid='{0}'">

       <FilterParameters><asp:ControlParameter Name="" ControlID="ArtistID" PropertyName="Value"/>  
        </FilterParameters>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the ArtistID as a parameter, and also change your text box and submit button to ASP controls like so:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtArtistID" runat="server" /><br /><br />
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" CssClass="submit" />
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="Data Source=oracle2;User ID=******;Password=***********;Unicode=True" 
    ProviderName="System.Data.OracleClient" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM SPEEDOFSALEREPORT WHERE ARTISTID = @artistID;">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="artistID" ControlID="txtArtistID" PropertyName="Text" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Then bind the grid on the button click in your code behind (VB.NET):

```
Protected Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Or (C#):

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot for the idea. But I keep getting this error and cannot run  Literal content ('</SelectParameter>        </asp:SqlDataSource>          </div>      </form>  </body>  </html>') is not allowed within a 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ParameterCollection'.

Comment: Try removing your outer form tag and placing everything inside form1.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I updated the code in original post. Could you please take a look at it ?

Comment: It looks like you might be missing the closing SqlDataSource tag </asp:SqlDataSource> after your select parameter.

Comment: I had. I forgot to copy all of them.

Comment: You are also missing an 's' on the end of </SelectParameters>. That should be what your original error was complaining about.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        if (TextBox1.Text != ""){
        con.Open();
        int i = 0;
        SqlCommand cmd0 = new SqlCommand("select noticeid from TBLnotice where noticeid='" + TextBox1.Text + "'", con);
        i= int.Parse(cmd0.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        if (i > 0){
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select notice from TBLnotice where noticeid='" + TextBox1.Text + "'", con);
            string name = cmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            txtadds.Text = name;
            TextBox1.Text = "";
            txtadds.Text = "";
            con.Close();
        }
        else{
            Label7.Visible = true;
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A block of code is not really an answer. Please elaborate.